# Установка OpenSSL для Python3

Tags: python, openssl, pip

При установке

```
pip3 instal pyopenssl
```

Ошибка:

> Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-mycc1h6w/cffi Storing debug log for failure in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log

Последние строчки лога

```
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l_hkw94a/cffi
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/todo-api/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/root/todo-api/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 304, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/root/todo-api/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/root/todo-api/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/root/todo-api/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l_hkw94a/cffi
```

Система `Linux-3.19.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.04-vivid`

```
Dezmont@137407:~$ /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import OpenSSL'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    if _lib.Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST:
AttributeError: 'FFILibrary' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: пробовали `sudo apt-get install python3-openssl`?

Comment: Пробовал не помогло

Comment: что значит "не помогло"? Что `dpkg -l python3-openssl` показывает?  Какая ошибка: `/usr/bin/python3 -c OpenSSL`?

Comment: @jfs вот как то так получается при установке cryptography тоже ошибка, но другая. Можешь сам глянуть, пароль дам. А то я уже всю голову сломал

Comment: `python3 -с OpenSSL` это моя ошибка. Я имел в виду: `/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import OpenSSL'`. (не забудьте `/usr/bin/`)

Answer (score -1):

Проблему решил удалением старой версии pip

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/{dist,site}-packages/pip*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/{dist,site}-packages/pillow*
```

[Ответ тут нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301121/how-to-recover-from-pip-freeze-exception?answertab=votes&newreg=d1bef9dbf45a4a5889d27cd224a2629f)

Comment: команды, которые пытаются удалить сломанную инсталяцию `pip` для Python **2**, не имеют никакого отношения к установке пакета на Python **3**.

Comment: @jfs Может и не имеют. Но все наконец заработало, а это главное